# How to constraint multiplication of certain parameters to constant value in lmfit?

Tags: constraints, lmfit

I have a model with several parameters, say "A", "B" and "C". They all are set varying with some min and max bounds, motivated by their representation of physical quantities.

In addition, I'd need to constraint their product to certain value (say 1), such as "A" * "B" * "C" == 1.

I tried:

```py
p.add('mult_constraint", expr = 'A*B*C==1)
```

,but that throws an error:
NameError: at expr='<ast.Module object at 0x0000014A546EAFD0>'

How would constraint like this need to be written?

Comment: What is the context? What programming language and/or system, environment? We need more information please.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to define three parameters `A`, `B`, and `C`, with the constraint that `ABC=1`.   That could look like:

```
 import lmfit
 params = lmfit.Parameters()
 params.add('A', value=0.75, min=0)
 params.add('B', value=5.50, min=0.25)
 params.add('C', expr='1/(A*B)')
```

That is, the constraint means that one of your parameters is not actually varying independently but determined by the constraint and the values of the other parameters.